# Calculate Average of Price per Items per Month in a Few Years Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, moving-average

I have this table inside my postgresql database,

```
item_code |    date    | price
==============================
aaaaaa.1  |2019/12/08  | 3.04
bbbbbb.b  |2019/12/08  | 19.48
261893.c  |2019/12/08  | 7.15
aaaaaa.1  |2019/12/17  | 4.15
bbbbbb.2  |2019/12/17  | 20
xxxxxx.5  |2019/03/12  | 3
xxxxxx.5  |2019/03/18  | 4.5
```

how can i calculate the average per item, per month over the year. so i get the result something like:

```
item_code |  month  | price
==============================
aaaaaa.1  | 2019/12 | 3.59
bbbbbb.2  | 2019/12 | 19.74
261893.c  | 2019/12 | 7.15
xxxxxx.5  | 2019/03 | 3.75
```

I have tried to look and apply many alternatives but i am still not get the point, would really appreciate your help because i am new to postgresql.

Comment: it's not a "moving average", it is simply a group by `date_trunc('month', date)` and `item_code`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how the question relates to a *moving* average. It seems you just want `group by`:

```
select item_code, date_trunc('month', date) as date_month, avg(price) as price
from mytable
group by item_code, date_month
```

This gives `date_month` as a `date`, truncated to the first day of the month - which I find more useful that the format you suggested. But it you do want that:

```
to_char(date, 'YYYY/MM') as date_month
```